# redis : how to create multiple redis queue / message broker

Tags: redis

Redis is in-memory database and message broker.

Like we can create multiple databases in redis ,

so , like wise ,

how to create multiple (message broker/message queues) in redis?

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple queues by having multiple *lists*:

> Pattern: Reliable queue
>   Redis is often used as a messaging server to implement processing of background jobs or other kinds of messaging tasks. A simple form of queue is often obtained pushing values into a list in the producer side, and waiting for this values in the consumer side using RPOP (using polling), or BRPOP if the client is better served by a blocking operation.
>   However in this context the obtained queue is not reliable as messages can be lost, for example in the case there is a network problem or if the consumer crashes just after the message is received but it is still to process.
>   RPOPLPUSH (or BRPOPLPUSH for the blocking variant) offers a way to avoid this problem: the consumer fetches the message and at the same time pushes it into a processing list. It will use the LREM command in order to remove the message from the processing list once the message has been processed.
>   An additional client may monitor the processing list for items that remain there for too much time, and will push those timed out items into the queue again if needed.

Regarding:

> how to create multiple (message broker/message queues) in redis?

Each list is a different queue. Where you can have multiple senders and receivers.
Regarding the Broker: That'd be Redis. 
It also supports [pub/sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub).

[Source](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush)